# ShinyR : Insert user inputs in a database for further use

Tags: r, database, input, shiny

I'm using Shiny to develop a small app.

My problem of the day is to insert inputs from the user (reactive environment) into an existing dataframe. Specifically, I can't convert the inputs type from closure to double (see error message below).

I've already tried several approaches and googled the problem but didn't find any solution.

Thanks a lot,

**Here's a simplified version of the code:**

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
 navbarPage(title = "App Title",
         tabPanel("Panel Header",
                  titlePanel("Panel Title"),
                  sidebarLayout(
                    sidebarPanel("SideBar"),
                    mainPanel(
                      numericInput("User_1","Input1", value = 1, min=0),
                      numericInput("User_2","Input2", value = 0.3, min=0),
                      actionButton(inputId = "UserValid",label = "Click me"),
                      dataTableOutput("df")
    )#end mainPanel
  )#end sidebarLayout
)#end tabPanel
)#end Navbarpage
)#end ui


server <- function(input, output) {
  DB1 <- read.csv2("~/FilePathway/DB1.csv", row.names = 1, sep=",", dec=".")

UserData <- eventReactive(input$UserValid,{
data.frame(U_1 = input$User_1,
           U_2 = input$User_2
)})

DB1[66,1:2] <- eventReactive(input$UserValid,{
UserData()
})
}#end server

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Here's the error message**

```
Warning: Error in <-: incompatible types (from closure to double) in subassignment type fix
  52: [<-.data.frame
  50: server [#27]
Error in x[[jj]][iseq] <- vjj : 
  incompatible types (from closure to double) in subassignment type fix
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same issue, please go to this topic for a partial (at least for now) solution:
[ShinyR : Unexpected result when exporting inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55209822/shinyr-unexpected-result-when-exporting-inputs)